# JavaScript snippet containing multiple dollar signs is corrupted

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting, stack-snippets

As part of https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7848/163, I posted a stack snippet that uses jQuery and ran into a problem. Take for example the following snippet:

```
!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    $(function() {
      alert($('body').length);
    });

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- end snippet -->
```

The initial portion, starting with the first dollar sign and ending with the second dollar sign, seems to have been replaced with a GUID, like this:

[image: Corrupted stack snippet]

I worked around the issue by adding a `//$$` line at the beginning of the JavaScript snippet.

Interestingly, the snippet works fine until I save my answer, and I [could not reproduce the issue on this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272105/152416), until I tried indenting the snippet's Markdown code as a code block (to post it here) and got the following even before saving:

```
<pre>7167001d-945a-95b7-7930-180c7f7ee9f5</pre>
```

And yet after saving, a snippet inside a code block!

```
    $(function() {
      alert($('body').length);
    });
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why is this happening? It seems like a bug in the parser. Can it be fixed?

Comment: Also reported on [meta.PPCG](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5043/3808) and [meta.CR](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5063/36278).